# Как в Visual Studio Code настроить цвет фона для файлов разного типа?

Tags: visual-studio-code, color, settings

**settings.json** позволяет определить цвет фона для всех файлов:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
"editor.background": "#F0F8FF" }
```

Возможно ли настроить различные цвета фона, например, для файлов с расширениями **html**, **php** и **js** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На данный момент есть расширение [Theme by language](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jsaulou.theme-by-language). Оно позволяет выбирвть разные цветовые схемы в зависимости от языка. Однако бывают разные расширения файлов с одним и тем же языком и именно в таком ключе проблема не решается.

Есть [открытый вопрос](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/20652) в гитхабе разрабов VSCode по этому поводу. Коробочного решения пока нет.

Мне со своей стороны не удалось обнаружить в вёрстке VSСode CSS класс, в который бы явно попадало расширение файла/язык, чтобы использовать его в кастомной цветовой схеме.

Comment: Спасибо,  то что нужно!